# Help me find the reg-key which is preventing me from chaning excel macro security-level?

Tags: windows, excel, com

My automatic test-framework tests a bunch of Excel sheets required by our customers with the excel plugins that my team provides. In order to test the sheet I need to call some macros, this in turn requires macro security to be set to lowest on the testing servers. (In production macro security will be on). In particular I need to supress this dialog:

[image]

One particular PC seems to resist my attempts to configure it, having set macro security to low from Tools->Macro->Secyrity... I exit Excel and return to it, only to find out that macro security has been reverted to "medium"

I'm guessing that I've inherited a PC which has a registry setting that prevents me from downgrading the security, I've searched around and found "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Security]", however this does not seem to do the trick.

I wonder if there is another way to force macro security to it's lowest setting, either programmatically (via COM) or through a simple registry edit.

UPDATE: I'm on Office 2003. My PCs were pre-owned by other users and may have all kinds of configuration inconsistencies. Of all the PC's under my care this issue only affects one machine. I have full admin rights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security\VBAWarnings=1 (REG_DWORD) is the setting you're looking for.  It can also exist under HKLM as a machine-wide override. The location also varies by office version; 2003=11.0; 2007=12.0.

Lastly, if you are in a managed IT environment, keep in mind that group policy may be changing it back for you.

Comment: +1 and I agree about the managed environment.  We handle everything in regards to these type of messages thru policy control.  It might be easier than having to go around to 80+ machines if you work in a large company :)

Comment: Thanks, I have admin rights on all my test boxes, however these were pre-owned by regular users so some policy remnant may be in effect.

Comment: Are you saying that I set it to 1 in order to disable the messages? This does not seem to have an effect. I set it in HKCU and HKLM. When I load and excit Excel, the setting in in HKCU dissapears.

Comment: Yes, you set it to one to disable macro virus protection (enable all macros). Once you do that the messages will go away.